# how can i run hadoop streaming job in one cluster and write output to other cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I have 2 hadoop cluster with 2 different ugi. 
I want to run hadoop job in one cluster because the queue is empty, but i also want to output to other cluster because it's hdfs is empty, how can i do it.

Is there a way just like distcp (i can set source ugi and dest ugi) in a hadoop streaming job ?

thank you very mutch

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to write out results to `-output hdfs://namenode-2:port/path/data` in your output steps.

Otherwise, it might require [HDFS Federation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/Federation.html)